# html 5 tooltip integrated in browser showing wrong message

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html:

```
<input ng-disabled="disable" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-email ng-invalid-pattern ng-invalid-email-remove ng-touched" maxlength="50" ng-model="current.email" name="email" id="personEmail" pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="true" style="" type="email">
```

When submitting the form with an invalid email address, a tooltip error will show up close to the input field.
The text in the input field is different in each browser.
Firefox tooltip is not the same as chrome tooltip which is not the same as Explorer tooltip.

I thought it was my application that handled this. But now Im getting convinced it is somewhere else.
When searching for the text that shows in the tooltip among all my files, I could not find any trace of it.

So it is the browser itself that creates the message?

When mousing over the input field, I see the same text that will show up in case I enter wrong email like if it was an alt-tag.

What im looking for is to modify or, alternatively, remove this tooltip. The reason is that the for some strange reason the text in Explorer is incomplete.
While in the other browsers the message in the tooltip is quite understandable, in Explorer it states something like this (translating now from another language than english):

```
You must enter an email address in this format:
```

As yo can see, it asks for writing in the right format, but doesn't explain what the format is.

****EDIT***

This is the generated html:

```
<input ng-disabled="disable" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-email ng-invalid-pattern ng-invalid-email-remove ng-touched" maxlength="50" ng-model="current.email" name="email" id="personEmail" pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="true" style="" type="email">
```

Comment: "I have this html" — That isn't HTML. It's an Angular template. You should look at the DOM generated from it.

Comment: The [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) is an html5 attribute. This is indeed handled by the browser.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pattern attribute needs to contain a regex when specified, and this is what some browsers might display.

Comment: I updated the question with the generated html.

Comment: The pattern looks like this: pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"

Comment: According to html5 documentation at mozilla.org: "Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user.". I tried to put the title attribute in the input-tag. But it is not that that is displayed as an error. The error message still varies from browser to browser and I do not have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the input field:

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter on Alphabets ')"
```

solves the issue.